# How to change sdf parameter static from GUI plugin?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I created GUI plugin with button that spawns objects. For objects i have sdf files with default parameters. Only parameter that i change in plugin is pose, where i use mutable_pose like this:

```
    msgs::Set(msg_.mutable_pose(), ignition::math::Pose3d(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This is working correctly. Is there any way to do something similar for static parameter?
My sdf objects have static set to false, but i'd like to change it to true by clicking button. Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23873/how-to-change-sdf-parameter-static-from-gui-plugin?/) by [Boris94](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16899/boris94/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I assume you're using a `gazebo::msgs::Factory` message to spawn your models.  As you can see in the [message description](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/msgs/factory.proto), there's a field to override `pose`, which you're using, but no field to override `static`. So one thing you could do is edit the model's SDF before spawning.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1